# Does the dialog with followers change based on the hero's class?

Tags: diablo-iii

**Does everybody "know their roots" in the Diablo Universe?**

Last night I got into a conversation with my Templar where I encouraged him to try and remember "his sins" as it were, which he had been forced to forget as part of his initiation into the Templar order.

My Witch Doctor suggested that he grind a particular type of root, which is said to have memory restorative powers.  This seems like an awfully Witch-Doctor-y thing to suggest.

The Templar seemed to think this was a good idea, but I'm kind of wondering how this would have played out had I been a different class with perhaps less knowledge of herbal remedies.  Perhaps the Templar's reaction is generic, but the hero's dialog is class-specific?

Does the dialog with followers change based on your class?  Does gender matter at all?  If it does change, do the follower's responses change, or just my hero's dialog?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, dialog is different depending on your class. The conversations that can be had are the same, but the composition of those conversations can be different for different classes. If you go to ZAM's (the owners of Wowhead) Diablo 3 database, you can view conversations as they would happen depending on which class you are playing.

[image: A quest conversation as a Wizard on D3DB.com]

Answer (score 2):

While the amount of conversation options with your Followers remain consistent from playthrough to playthrough, regardless of class, the dialogue varies, both for your hero and the NPC.

Generally, though, the dialogue follows the same sort of progression from class to class. My monk didn't suggest any herb-healing remedies to the Templar, but the Templar still began to learn of his past regardless.

Comment: Do we know if it also varies with *gender*?

Answer (score 1):

The dialog most definitely depends on your character class, both the lines spoken by the hero as well as the lines spoken by the NPCs.